# Terraform - loop over complex data in data source

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-route53

I am trying to configure records on aws by looping instructions from my data source.

the data source looks like this:

```
data "dns_instructions" "example-dns-instructions" {
    id      = "123"
    instructions {
        name   = "www.example.com"
        type   = "A"
        value  = "1.2.3.4"
    }

    instructions {
        name   = "a.example.com"
        type   = "TXT"
        value  = "value 1"
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "my-records" {
  for_each = {
      for inst in data.dns_instructions.example-dns-instructions.instructions : 
         "${inst.id}" => inst
    }
  zone_id = "ABCSDSD....."
  name    = each.value.name
  type    = each.value.type
  ttl     = 300
  records = each.value.value
}
```

I do see the data source with all details in the TF state but when trying to apply, getting:

```
data.dns_instructions.example-dns-instructions.instructions is null
│
│ A null value cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.
```

I am probably missing something basic in terraform, can someone please assist?

Comment: Are instructions with a fixed value as in the data source?